# Add two images and two text in video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i raw_video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=24:x=20:y=259[text];[text][1:v]overlay=215:0[filtered]" -map "[filtered]" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

this code can add a photo and a text to image but can i add multiple photo and text at same time in video ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i raw_video.mp4 -i watermark.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex 
 "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='text1':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=24:x=20:y=259,
   drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:text='text2':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=24:x=500:y=500[text];
  [text][1:v]overlay=215:0[ol1];[ol1][2:v]overlay=400:300[filtered]" 
-map "[filtered]" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy output.mp4
```